# why is this for cycle skipping the 1st iteration?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

The 2nd iteration of the `for` loop always skips the 1st iteration. In debugging mode, it starts with `i=1`, but as soon as it computes the if clause,    `i=2` and for the rest it goes nice. It's almost as if there's n hidden `continue`.

### Original Code:

```
int n, k, i, j = 0;
int *key;
int x = 0;
int y = 0;

scanf ("%d%d", &n, &k);
key = malloc (n * sizeof (int));

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    scanf("%d", &key[i]);
}


    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        if (key[j % n] == i) {
            x++;
        } else {
            y++;
            j++;
        }           
    }
```

The code this way works perfectly though:

```
 while (1) {
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        while (1) {
            if (x == k) {
                printf("%d",y);
                return 0;
            } else if (!(key[j % n] - i)) {
                x++;    
                break;
            } else {
                y++;
                j++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you turn optimalisations on? the compiler can notice that the first if statement in the loop is always false because `0 % n` cannot be `1`.

Comment: Oh thank you, without optimization it seems to be working. But 0%n should give 0 index to array, it's a legitimate value

Comment: With optimization on, the compiler could generate a goto to start the loop at the else{  y++; j++;}, or it could start the loop with i=2, y=1, j=1. You could add a printf() in the else{...} section to see what is going on.

Comment: Are you using the same variable `i` on purpose in both loops? I would always keep it local by declaring it in the for statement. This does probably not solve your, but still.

Comment: @ usr1234567 you can't do that in c, can you?